# Symmetries and KdV

Tags: partial-differential-equations, lie-groups, lie-algebras, fake-proofs

I would like to find the value of $\alpha$ such that

$$
 V=\frac{\partial}{\partial u}+\alpha t \frac{\partial}{\partial x}
$$
generates a Lie symmetry of the KdV equation.

I found that the generated group of symmetries is
\begin{align*}
(\tilde{x}  ,\tilde{t}  ,\tilde{u}  )=g^{\epsilon} (x,\epsilon,u) = (\alpha  t \epsilon +  x, t, u +  \epsilon).
\end{align*}
So I thought that I should plug this in to the KdV equation given the new variables. That is I calculated
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial  \tilde{u}  }{\partial  \tilde{t}} = \frac{\partial  u}{\partial  t}  \quad 
\frac{\partial  \tilde{u}  }{\partial  \tilde{x}} = \alpha \epsilon \frac{\partial  u}{\partial  t}  +  \frac{\partial  u}{\partial  x} \quad
\frac{\partial ^3\tilde{u}   }{\partial   \tilde{x}  ^3   } = \alpha ^3 \epsilon ^3 \frac{\partial ^3u   }{\partial   t  ^3   } + 3 \alpha ^2 \epsilon ^2 \frac{\partial ^3u   }{\partial   t  ^2   \partial   x   } + 3 \alpha \epsilon \frac{\partial ^3u   }{\partial   t   \partial   x  ^2   }+ \frac{\partial ^3u   }{\partial   x  ^3   }.
\end{aligned}$$
I then tried to plug it in the new kdv equation and see for what value of $\alpha $ it works
\begin{align*}
\tilde{u}  _{\tilde{x}  \tilde{x}  \tilde{x}  } +  \tilde{u}  _{\tilde{t}  }-6 \tilde{u}  \tilde{u}  _{\tilde{x}  }=0
\end{align*}
but the $\epsilon$ are causing me issues. In partulcar I got
\begin{align*}
\alpha ^3 \epsilon ^3 \frac{\partial ^3u   }{\partial   t  ^3   } + 3 \alpha ^2 \epsilon ^2 \frac{\partial ^3u   }{\partial   t  ^2   \partial   x   } + 3 \alpha \epsilon \frac{\partial ^3u   }{\partial   t   \partial   x  ^2   } +   -6 \left(  \epsilon\right) \left(\alpha \epsilon \frac{\partial  u}{\partial  t}  +  \frac{\partial  u}{\partial  x}\right) -6 u \alpha \epsilon \frac{\partial u }{\partial t} =0
\end{align*}
This clearly can not impose a condition on $\alpha$

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are wrong:

> $$\frac{\partial  \tilde{u}  }{\partial  \tilde{t}} = \frac{\partial  u}{\partial  t}  \quad 
> \frac{\partial  \tilde{u}  }{\partial  \tilde{x}} = \alpha \epsilon \frac{\partial  u}{\partial  t}  +  \frac{\partial  u}{\partial  x}$$

When doing chain rule for partial derivatives you have to invert your coordinate transformation, since in general $\frac{\partial  a}{\partial  b} \neq 1/(\frac{\partial  b}{\partial  a})$. So in this case we have
$$
(x,t,u)= (\tilde{x} - \alpha \epsilon \tilde{t}, \tilde{t}, \tilde{u}-\epsilon)
$$
And then we get
$$
\frac{\partial  \tilde{u}  }{\partial  \tilde{t}} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial  \tilde{t}} = \frac{\partial  u  }{\partial  x}\frac{\partial  x }{\partial  \tilde{x}} + \frac{\partial  u  }{\partial  t}\frac{\partial  t  }{\partial  \tilde{t}} = -\alpha \epsilon \frac{\partial  u  }{\partial  x} + \frac{\partial  u}{\partial  t}
$$
and by a similar method
$$
\frac{\partial  \tilde{u}  }{\partial  \tilde{x}} = \frac{\partial  u}{\partial  x}
$$
The rest of the question should be straightforward from here.